# VBA script to find matches between column L on sheet 1 and column A on sheet 2 then paste the row that matches on sheet 3

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim ii As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sheet1LastRow As Long
Dim sheet2LastRow As Long

sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Final").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("2015new").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To sheet1LastRow
        For ii = 2 To sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("2015new").Cells(ii, 1).Value Then
              Worksheets("2015new").Rows(ii & ":" & ii).Copy Sheets("Extract").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            Else
            End If
    Next ii
Next j
```

Looked around forums and came up with the codes above but it doesn't seem to work. It also buffers for a while before coming back with nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Some extra info, both columns consist of dates and they do not amount the same. ( meaning sheet 1 has around 100rows of dates while sheet 2 has 20krows )

Comment: `Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("2015new").Cells(ii, 1).Value` checks both at column A.... shouldn't one of them be `Cells(*, 12)`? asuming "Final" is sheet1 -> `Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 12).Value`...

Comment: @DirkReichel Yes you are right ! Mistake on my part ! Now the problem is the program takes a very long time to finish looping through the columns. Is there any way to shorten this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just looking for speed, something like this should help a lot:

```
Dim chkRng As Variant, runRng As Range, outRng As Range, i As Long
chkRng = Worksheets("Final").Range("L1", Worksheets("Final").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
For Each runRng In Worksheets("2015new").Range("A2", Worksheets("2015new").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  For i = 2 To UBound(chkRng)
    If chkRng(i, 1) = runRng.Value Then
      If outRng Is Nothing Then Set outRng = runRng.EntireRow Else Set outRng = Union(outRng, runRng.EntireRow)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next
If Not outRng Is Nothing Then outRng.Copy Sheets("Extract").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: it says compile error expected array in line :  For i1 = 2 To UBound(chkRng)   .  The word UBound is highlighted . Any idea why?

Comment: @mrwave oh sorry... chkRng is Variant and not a Range... should work now

Answer (score 0):

I have make some changes on your code, hope it help. (Not tested)

```
Dim ii As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sheet1LastRow As Long
Dim sheet2LastRow As Long

sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Final").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("2015new").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To sheet1LastRow
        For ii = 2 To sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("Final").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("2015new").Cells(ii, 1).Value Then
              Worksheets("2015new").Rows(ii).Copy Sheets("Extract").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)

            Else
            End If
    Next ii
Next j
```